# how can i get different combinations of arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have the array like this

```
array1 =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
array2 =  ['1', '2', '3']
array3 =  ['a', 'b']
```

I want to have different combinations to get the result in array like this

`['A@1@a', 'A@1@b', 'A@2@a', 'A@2@b'  . . .. ]`

Logic is

1. Take the first element of array 1
2. Then take first element of array 2
3. at this point we get `A@1` then for all elements of array 3 , we get `'A@1@a', 'A@1@b'`

Then we repeat it. i am seprarting each array with `@`
How can i do that

Comment: Can you describe the logic between those seemingly completely different things?

Comment: it's like a product cartesian

Comment: EDIT: You obviously understand the logic behind this, now have a close look at a for-loop

Comment: @jeroen , with the simple for loop i can do that , i was thinking if there is some array cartesian function to that.

Comment: Oh well, I answered it, but it's on hold. Here it is working: https://eval.in/83514

Answer (score 4):

```
$totalArray = array();
foreach($array1 as $a1) {
    foreach($array2 as $a2) {
        foreach($array3 as $a3) {
            $totalArray[] = "$a1@$a2@$a3";
        }
    }
}
```